# Whats come first on the constructor args, simple or complex arguments?

Tags: php, constructor, coding-style, arguments

I'm in doubt if i put complex constructor parameters first or at the end of constructor arguments, what is the correct way and why?:

```
function __construct(Reflector $reflector, $autoResolve, $canUseAnnotations);
```

Or:

```
function __construct($autoResolve, $canUseAnnotations, Reflector $reflector);
```

Note: $autoResolve and $canUseAnnotations are just simple boolean vars.

Comment: The only restriction is that you put optional arguments (those with default values) at the end, anything else is up to the individual coder

Comment: So, there's no standard for it, is it?

Comment: as @MarkBaker said, the optional arguments need to be at the end. and that's the only restriction. There is no standard i'm aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark already pointed out, its totally up to you how you order your params.
The most important part of this is consistency (see PHPs inconsistency in terms of str/array functions), which means that if you have more such classes, you should order your parameters as equally as possible upon those classes.

As to your question itself (and the next part is my personal opinion); I like to put the more complex parameters rather left then right. I dont know why, but it just feels right to me.